# Using an Attribute (IOperationBehavior) on all service methods

Tags: wcf

I am using the following [TrackingBehaviorAttribute] together with a custom IOperationInvoker on some [OperationContract] and everything is fine.

But I seek a way to be able to add this attribute on interface level ([ServiceContract] level).
I want to avoid the manual process of adding the attribute on every method inside a service.

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;    

public class TrackingBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
    {
        #region IOperationBehavior Members
        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription,
                                         BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription,
                                        ClientOperation clientOperation)
        {
        }

        public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription,
                                          DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            MethodInfo currMethodInfo = operationDescription.SyncMethod;
            CUSTOMOperationInvoker invoker = new CUSTOMOperationInvoker
                                          (dispatchOperation.Invoker, currMethodInfo);

            dispatchOperation.Invoker = invoker;
            invoker.OnInvokeEnded += new EventHandler<TrackingEventArgs>(/* logWriterMethod! */);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I have tried to modify the attribute to include IServiceBehavior as follows:

```
public class TrackingBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior, IOperationBehavior
{
    #region IServiceBehavior Members
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach ()
        {
            //Some loop to add this attribute to all service operation.
        }
    }
    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    #endregion
```

But I cant seem to get it to work. Am I approaching this wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have with the help of @ErnieL got the attribute to work on service-level but now when applied to multiple services I get following error when starting the host:

```
"The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains
an item of the same type: 'Tracking.TrackingServiceBehaviorAttribute'.
This collection only supports one instance of each type."
```

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop you are looking for is something like this:

```
public virtual void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{
    foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in serviceDescription.Endpoints)
    {
        foreach (OperationDescription operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
        {
            // TrackingBehaviorAttribute is your code that implements IOperationBehavior
            operation.Behaviors.Add(new TrackingBehaviorAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more examples [Carlos Figueira Extensibility blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx) is the place to read.

Comment: Do you care to elaborate a little, the attribute doesnt get used at all.

So I have ONE attribute that inherit both IServiceBehavior and IOperationBehavior and implements them both. I inserted the loop you provided but as I said the TrackingBehaviorAttribute is never used when applied to a service.

I tried separating the two attributes and make IServiceBehavior call IOperationBehavior but no luck. Meybe Im writing it wrong.

I only need the IOperationBehavior Attribute that I have to get applied on all service operations..

Comment: Thank you, I was actually using the attribute [TrackingServiceBehaviorAttribute] on the interface and not the implementation class. I saw the examples on [Carlos Blog you mentioned](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/16/wcf-extensibility-behaviors.aspx)

Comment: Please include details instead of adding a broken link to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This time I tried using IContractBehavior and it seems to work.

```
public class TrackingContractBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior, IOperationBehavior
{
    #region IContractBehavior Members
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        foreach (OperationDescription operation in contractDescription.Operations)
        {
            operation.Behaviors.Add(new Tracking.TrackingContractBehaviorAttribute());
        }
    }
    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region IOperationBehavior Members
    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        MethodInfo currMethodInfo = operationDescription.SyncMethod;
        TrackingOperationInvoker invoker = new TrackingOperationInvoker(dispatchOperation.Invoker, currMethodInfo); 
//TrackingOperationInvoker is my own custom invoker to start some functions before default invoker.

        dispatchOperation.Invoker = invoker;
        invoker.OnInvokeEnded += new EventHandler<TrackingEventArgs>(logWriter);
    }
```